# How to get rid of ? in the URL when passing data via link component in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am passing data via link component like this:

```
<div>
        {data.map((myData) => (
          <h2>
            <Link
            href={{
              pathname: `/${myData.title}`,
              query: {
                id: myData.id
              }
            }}>
            <a>{myData.title}</a>
            </Link>
          </h2>
        ))}
</div>
```

And getting this URL `http://localhost:3000/this-is-a-title?id=630f3c32c1`

Is there any other way to do the same but get rid of that ? and everything after it for better SEO?

Comment: I need that id to fetch content.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=next.js+seo+friendly+URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your path like so:

```js
<Link
  href={{
    // http://localhost:3000/this-is-a-title/630f3c32c1
    pathname: `/${myData.title}/${myData.id}`,
  }}>
  {myData.title}
</Link>
```

or any other format that works in your case e.g.

```js
// http://localhost:3000/this-is-a-title:630f3c32c1
pathname: `/${myData.title}:${myData.id}`,
```

With React Router Dom you should be able to pick up the id using params

Comment: Have a look at this post, it has an example when using `/{id}` hope it helps https://www.kindacode.com/snippet/next-js-retrieve-url-params-from-dynamic-routes/